# Replacing data source only if feature exists using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, layers, data-source

What would I need to add to my code to check that a data source exists first before running layer.replacedatasource?

I have been supplied with an example that uses the `os.path.isfile` to check if a shapefile exists within a folder specified by the user first and then will replace it.

If it does not exist then it will remove the layer from the mxd. This works perfectly.

I have tried using the same code lines but instead using a feature class with the user now inputting the geodatabase. When I run the updated code it comes up with layer: Unexpected error and I can't understand what is going wrong. If remove the os.path.isfile and replace it with if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE") it works until it comes across a feature class that does not exist and layer: Unexpected error returns. I have copied both scripts for comparison.

```
import arcpy, os, shutil

#Tool paramaters---------------
dataFrom = "Salisbury"
GisFolder = r"D:\Projects\1234\GIS"
geodatabase = r"D:\Projects\1234\GIS\Databases\Test.gdb"
projectNumber = "1234"
siteName = "Test"
studyArea = r"D:\Projects\1234\GIS\Test_StudyArea"
try:
    # set up the designated data path - required at this stage for setting up MXD links
    eh_listedBuildingPointPath = os.path.join(geodatabase, siteName + "_" + projectNumber + "_HE_ListedBuildings")

    # set up paths to locate data
    if dataFrom == "Salisbury":
        lbPtPath = "X:\GIS\Data\HistoricEngland\Listed Buildings\ListedBuildings.shp"

    #make feature layer for spatial selecting
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(lbPtPath, "ListedBuildings_lyr_HE")

    #select designated sites within the studyArea
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("ListedBuildings_lyr_HE", "INTERSECT", studyArea)
    featuresCount = arcpy.GetCount_management("ListedBuildings_lyr_HE")
    if str(featuresCount) == "0":
        arcpy.AddMessage("No Listed Buildings")
    else:
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("ListedBuildings_lyr_HE", eh_listedBuildingPointPath)
        
    # --- Template source -template can come from a number of locations if it is a variable.
    if dataFrom == "Salisbury":
        srcMXD = "X:/GIS/_Templates/Heritage.mxd"
    elif dataFrom == "Sheffield":
        srcMXD = "S:/GIS/_Templates/Heritage.mxd"
    else:
        srcMXD = "R:/GIS/_Templates/Heritage.mxd"
    
    # Create destination path
    dstMXDName = projectNumber + "_" + siteName + "_Setup.mxd"
    dstMXD = os.path.join(GisFolder,"MXD",dstMXDName)
    shutil.copy(srcMXD,dstMXD)
    
    # Get data frame for removing and updating layers
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(dstMXD)
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]

    #loop through the dstMXD - remove or fix sources
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):

        #remove layers from the mxd if the featureclass weren't created - this loop does not work with os.path.isfile
        if lyr.name == "Historic England Listed Buildings":
            if os.path.isfile(eh_listedBuildingPointPath):
                lyr.replaceDataSource(geodatabase, "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", siteName + "_" + projectNumber + "_HE_ListedBuildings")
            else:
                arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
    # Save the MXD
    mxd.save()
except Exception as e:
    arcpy.AddError(e)


import arcpy, os, shutil

#Tool paramaters---------------
dataFrom = "Salisbury"
GisFolder = r"D:\Projects\1234\GIS"
projectNumber = "1234"
siteName = "Test"
studyArea = r"D:\Projects\1234\GIS\Test_StudyArea"
try:
    # Set up folder path
    shpFolder = os.path.join(GisFolder, "SHP")

    # set up the designated data path - required at this stage for setting up MXD links
    eh_listedBuildingPointPath = os.path.join(shpFolder, siteName + "_" + projectNumber + "_HE_ListedBuildings.shp")

    # set up paths to locate data
    if dataFrom == "Salisbury":
        lbPtPath = "X:\GIS\Data\HistoricEngland\Listed Buildings\ListedBuildings.shp"

    #make feature layer for spatial selecting
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(lbPtPath, "ListedBuildings_lyr_HE")

    #select designated sites within the studyArea
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("ListedBuildings_lyr_HE", "INTERSECT", studyArea)
    featuresCount = arcpy.GetCount_management("ListedBuildings_lyr_HE")
    if str(featuresCount) == "0":
        arcpy.AddMessage("Listed Buildings")
    else:
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("ListedBuildings_lyr_HE", eh_listedBuildingPointPath)

    # --- Template source -template can come from a number of locations if it is a variable.
    if dataFrom == "Salisbury":
        srcMXD = "X:/GIS/_Templates/Heritage.mxd"
    elif dataFrom == "Sheffield":
        srcMXD = "S:/GIS/_Templates/Heritage.mxd"
    else:
        srcMXD = "R:/GIS/_Templates/Heritage.mxd"

    # Create destination path
    dstMXDName = projectNumber + "_" + siteName + "_Setup.mxd"
    dstMXD = os.path.join(GisFolder,"MXD",dstMXDName)
    shutil.copy(srcMXD,dstMXD)

    # Get data frame for removing and updating layers
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(dstMXD)
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]

    #loop through the dstMXD - remove or fix sources
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):

        #remove layers from the mxd if the featureclass weren't created - this loop does not work with os.path.isfile
        if lyr.name == "Historic England Listed Buildings":
            if os.path.isfile(eh_listedBuildingPointPath):
                lyr.replaceDataSource(lbPtPath, "SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE", siteName + "_" + projectNumber + "_HE_ListedBuildings")
            else:
                arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
    # Save the MXD
    mxd.save()
except Exception as e:
    arcpy.AddError(e)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Exists](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/exists.htm):

> Determines the existence of the specified data object. This function
> tests for the existence of various data types including feature
> classes, tables, datasets, shapefiles, workspaces, layers, and files.
> The function returns a Boolean indicating whether the element exists.

Comment: Thanks for the information @BERA I tried using arcpy.Exists() but it still is coming up with the same error.                                   `if lyr.name == "Historic England Listed Buildings":
            if arcpy.Exists (eh_listedBuildingPointPath):
                lyr.replaceDataSource(geodatabase, "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", siteName + "_" + projectNumber + "_HE_ListedBuildings")
            else:
                arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)`

Comment: I have managed to get it to work with arcpy.Exists. For some reason it did not like applying the siteName and projectNumber within lyr.replacedatasource. So, to work around this I removed them from lyr.replacedatasource and from eh_listedBuildingPointPath.